# Magento Ajax Static Block Call

Tags: ajax, magento, content-management-system

folks.

I've been searching for a solution but all I get is some fragments of what I need. I am trying to display some extra content on the footer. This content will be displayed when a footer link is clicked. I can do that easily with some code like:

```
<!-- TRIGGER -->
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return abreInfo();">Sobre</a></li>

<!-- CONTAINER -->
<div id="infoShow">
    <section> ... </section>
</div>

<!-- SCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript">

function abreInfo(id) {
    jQuery("#infoShow").slideDown('fast', function () {
        jQuery('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery("#infoShow").offset().top -54 }, 200);
    });
}
</script>
```

Although this is not actually what I need. Because the content inside the section needs to be a CMS Static Block, and there will be more than one Static Block to load, according to the footer link the user click (what I'm trying to do is a AJAX call of the footer links, like 'about', 'payment methods', 'delivery info', etc.). Unfortunately knowledge leads me to this kind of script:

```
function abreInfo(id) {
    jQuery("#infoShow").slideDown('fast', function () {
        jQuery('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery("#infoShow").offset().top -54 }, 200);
            jQuery("#infoShow>section").load("<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('" + id + "')->toHtml() ?>", function () { 
        });
    });
}
```

But, as you may see, I am using a php echo inside javascript, disabling all the script. What I am not being able to resolute is a way to get the CMS Static Block ID by clicking on the 'a' element and printing it on the javascript function.

Looking on the web, I've found a code that may be helpfull, but I am not pretty sure of how to deal with that:

```
$block_identifier = $_GET['id'];
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($block_identifier);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must load your static block to div which will be hidden, then after click footer link you must show div. for example

```
<div id="hiddenBlock" style="display:hidden">
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('static_block_id')->toHtml() ?>
</div>
<div>
<a href="#" onclick="showBlock()">show block</a>
</div>
```

and js function

```
function showBlock() {
 jQuery('#hiddenBlock').show();
}
```

Something like that, this is simplest solution without Ajax loading

Comment: Yes, Kuba_ceg, it would be a simple solution. But it is not actually what I need, because there will be more than one Static Block and making all these being rendered when the page loads aint a good solution. I need to call each Block only when the function are triggered. Thanks anyway.

Comment: So I think you must create simple controller which will show static block content. This is quite simple